# Make header and slideshow fit 100% of screen size

Tags: html, css, viewport

I would like the header and the slideshow (the top two elements of my site) to fit 100% of the screen size, no matter what the screen size is. I have tried using 100vh, however once you open the site on mobile the viewport size does not account for the address bar and page controls. Because of this I am now trying to use flex combined with height:100%, however this is not working either.

Here is an example of what I'm tying to get- https://www.rebag.com (the header and slideshow always perfectly fit the screen no matter what screen size)

```css
.slide-head-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header-top-bar-wrapper {
  height: 167px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.slide-connected {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="slide-head-wrapper">
  <div class="header-top-bar-wrapper">
    ///HEADER CODE GOES HERE////
  </div>
  <div class="slide-connected">
    ///SLIDER CODE GOES HERE////
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried using a manifest file?? https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest (refer to section on display)